# How to execute a plugin code inside a dart isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

In my app i need to listen to firebase notification. Firebase background notification can be handled by using the `onBackgroundMessage`. I want to print on a thermal printer as soon as this notification arrives, this requires to call a method from the plugin library inside this background notification handler function, but when calling the method i am getting this error
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method printLabel on channel bluetooth_print/methods)`
How to go about this?